# What should I write in the "Edit" view code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im new to MVC and I want to learn how to make the Edit View to work. I've searched a lot in the internet, but there is not much people who use code similar to mine.

This is what I have right now in the Edit property:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int Id=0)
    {
        MoviesData movie = db.MoviesData.Find(Id);
        MovieViewModel MovieVM = new MovieViewModel
        {
            MovieID = movie.MovieID,
            MovieName = movie.MovieName,
            MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
            MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
            MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
        };

        return View(MovieVM);
    }
```

'MoviesData' is the table in my database.
'MovieViewModel' contains the properties for the data.
The Edit View is the auto generated view of MVC.

what should i add to this to make it work?

Comment: Define "work". What do you want the code to do? In order to edit something, you must have two action methods: one to render the form (GET) and one to process the user input (POST). Have you tried following a tutorial or two?

Comment: Well, for now in the view it appears the edit template of MVC with the data of the record in the text boxes. However when I try to click to update, it doesnt. I want to make it update. I know there's missing stuff in the controller and I've searched and watched a few tutorials, but all of them use the "using <database> db = new <database>" witch doesnt apply with the code I have. Should I delete what I have and try that way?

Comment: @CodeCaster Ok, an update, I found a tutorial deep in internet. I was able to do the Create view. I will keep trying to solve my problems. If i cant I will ask again.

Answer (score -1):

copy & paste the code from create view and make the MovieID hidden field also change the redirection code create to edit .

Comment: @Diogo Teixeira if you're not understand then below link will guide you step by step.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application